# Magento 2 how to get product Ids in the Product listing page without pagination

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation, pagination, product-listing

I want to get the listed product's IDs in the product listing page without pagination. But the products will be listed with pagination.

If it is filtered by layered navigation/search then I want that filtered collection without pagination.

How can I do it?

Comment: you can get product data by category which assign products.

Comment: @DivyarajsinhBarad What about layered navigation?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom block that is active only for the category layout (`catalog_category_view.xml`).

This block would use the product collection and would filter the product by category id. When the category page is loaded, the registry current_category (`$registry->registry('current_category')->getId();`) is set. The code below would give you all the product ids.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addCategoriesFilter([$categoryId]);
$productIds = $collection->getAllIds();
```

Once done, I would advise to set a cache lifetime to this block so that it does not slow down your category pages.